# magento 2 unhide any messages

Tags: magento2.3, uicomponent, knockoutjs, messages, error-message

As per default Magento 2 behavior, any message like success, error or notice, etc hide after 5 seconds. 
I don't want to hide any message so that user can read message.

See below image that display error message but hide after 5 seconds.
[image]

I have override below files but not affect at all.

```
ROOT_FOLDER/vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js

ROOT_FOLDER/vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

I have put above two files in my theme like below.

```
ROOT_FOLDER/app/design/frontend/Abc/xyz/Magento_Ui/web/js/view/messages.js

ROOT_FOLDER/app/design/frontend/Abc/xyz/Magento_Theme/web/js/view/messages.js
```

But not working. Please help me how to unhide M2 messages.

Comment: Have you try my answer?

Comment: Is the issue resolved?

Comment: No issue not resolved yet. Chirag patel you have answered for checkout page error and I am looking for general messages.

Comment: @HirenShah I give the answer for checkout because in your question I have to see an image of the checkout page.
And it is doesn't matter because in all Magento logic is the same for hiding message.

Comment: And in your question, you have mentioned `unhide Any message`

Answer (score 1):

Overide the file

`vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js`

TO

`app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Ui/web/js/view/messages.js`

Comment Out the below code,

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
var self = this;
    // Hide message block if needed
    if (isHidden) {
       setTimeout(function () {
              $(self.selector).hide('blind', {}, 500);
       }, 5000);
}
```

Finally execute upgrade,Content commands

Comment: Hello arvind, How to override respected js file?

Comment: You just need to place the file in following location mentioned above. And comment out that if condition ..I have updated my answer check now

Answer (score 1):

Actually, Magento removes error message after a few time using `data-bind="visible: isVisible()` this visible function call timer and hide message after some time so just remove this code it will work.

Do not remove `data-bind="click` otherwise user cannot remove message.

Try to below way :

**Copy file from core Magento below-given path:**

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/template/messages.html

**Past in below path**

> app/design/frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/Magento_Ui/web/template/messages.html

Replace below code

```
div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages" data-bind="visible: isVisible(), click: removeAll">
```

With this code

```
<div data-role="checkout-messages" class="messages" data-bind="click: removeAll">
```

Run below command

> bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

I hope it helps! Thanks.

Comment: Hello Chirag Patel. Thanks for the update but this is not working. Still message hide after 5 deconds.

Comment: Remove var/* & generated/* folder and S:S:D -f and check.

Comment: Chirag Patel How to un-hide global message which display on top of page?